# What does "bumped to the homepage" mean?

Tags: discussion

I frequently see this, on older questions. Where do they end up?  If I add anything to them, is the OP likely to see it?

EDIT - okay, so it ends up at the top page in that 'forum' area, looking like an active question, but is not really.

Comment: See also: [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578)

Answer (score 1):

It will be bumped by "Community" which means an automated process. It is intended to bring questions with zero-score answers only back to the attention of everyone for further investigation. This does not apply to questions with negative scores.

See [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578)

> is the OP likely to see it?

Possibly not. I've seen quite old questions bumped, and the OP may have moved on. They will probably get an email notification however. Still, questions here are not just for the OP, and if you can give a good answer it may help someone else in the future.

Comment: Thank you Nick.

Comment: The flaw in this is that, without an answer having accepted by the OP (who may have abandoned it), the question is assumed to be unsolved. These questions seem to go on getting bumped back to the top every so often, forever.

Comment: You can always up-vote the answer(s) if it/they appears to be a good attempt to answer the question. In particular, if the OP doesn't say "that didn't work" you might default to assuming it worked.